# How to transfer one elasticsearch data to another elasticsearch by using filebeat as a middleware?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am having two elasticsearch with different versions, one is development and another one is production, so now i need to transfer the data of production to development elasticsearch, so is anyway to achieve this by using filebeat as a middleware?

Comment: Have you looked at cross cluster replication? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/ccr-getting-started.html

Comment: i need to transfer live data  of elasticsearch to another one, is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Filebeat is essentially to ship logs/data from files. Logstash would be a better candidate for this where your input as well as output would be elasticsearch. You can use the following config to ship data from one Elasticsearch host to another with Logstash as a middleware

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "<your-source-IP>"
  }
}


output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "<your-destination-IP>"
  }
}
```

Comment: The configuration is slightly more involved than just the IP, you have to deal with index, templates, confs...

Comment: is it possible to do same in filebeat?

Comment: No, filebeat reads log files, you need something that can read from one elasticsearch and send the data to another elasticsearch, you can use logstash for that.